# getServerSideProps implementation resulting different props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

I'm new in using NextJS and still learning about SSR, i had hard time understanding getServerSideProps() functionality, it's says that should replace useState for it be rendered on backend, but i got different props from what i gave to it and returning only some params attributes

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  return {
      props: {
        followNasa: true,
        user: {name:'name1', username:'username1', photoUrl:'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/62820033?v=4'}
      },
  };
}

export default function OverviewPage( props ) {
  return (
    <div className='w-full min-h-screen py-10 px-16 flex flex-col bg-gray-200'>
      <div>
        <p>user: {JSON.stringify(props.user)} & {JSON.stringify(props)}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

code above renders string:

```
user: & {"params":{},"searchParams":{}}
```

what causes this and how to correct it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code, and it works as expected. I've got:

```
user: {"name":"name1","username":"username1","photoUrl":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/62820033?v=4"} & {"followNasa":true,"user":{"name":"name1","username":"username1","photoUrl":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/62820033?v=4"}}
```

[You can see it running on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/frosty-morning-dypbik?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx)

**getServerSideProps** will work only when running `next dev` or `next start` because it needs an actual running server to be able to execute **getServerSideProps**.